# Wait command usage in Linux?

Tags: linux, bash, solaris, background-process, exit

```
#!/bin/bash
function back()
{
    sleep $1
    exit $2
}
back $1 $2 &
b=$!
if `wait $!`;then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
```

```
bash-3.00# ./back 300 0
failure
bash-3.00# ./back 300 1
failure
```

I was expecting `success` as exit status when I send 0, but I am still getting `failure`.

Also, `wait` doesn't wait for 300 seconds. Instead, I get the message immediately. I assume `$!` is the immediate child of `$$` in my script. Isn't it?

Is it possible to capture the exit status of wait like `exit_status=$(wait $!)`?

```
if ! ((exit_status));then
    echo sucess
else
    failure
fi
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that you're issuing `wait` in a subshell:

```
if `wait $!`;then
```

Because `wait` is a builtin, not a command, it's operating on the *subshell*, not your current shell.

The output that you would see but aren't is:

```
wait: pid 12344 is not a child of this shell
```

...with a return status of 1.

To perform your test you will need to do it without using a subshell.

```
#!/bin/bash
function back()
{
  sleep $1
  exit $2
}
back $1 $2 &
b=$!

wait $b && echo success || echo failure
```

This gives the result you expect, and waits as long as you expect:

```
$ time ./test.sh 3 0
success
./test.sh 3 0  0.00s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 3.012 total
$ time ./test.sh 3 1
failure
./test.sh 3 1  0.00s user 0.01s system 0% cpu 3.012 total
```

You can check the exit status of any command with `$?`:

```
$ /bin/true
$ echo $?
0
$ /bin/false
$ echo $?
1
```

---

There were a couple of other errors in your script. Your `#!` line was malformed, which I fixed. You assign `$!` to `$b`, but don't use `$b`.

Answer (score 12):

Remove the backticks.

As is, you're executing `wait` in a subshell, which doesn't have access to the parent shell's jobs, so it will immediately fail.

---

If you want the exit status, get the value of `$?` immediately after the wait.

```
command_here &
wait
status=$?
```

Answer (score 2):

Removing the backticks will make the program work, but not entirely because of the reasons already identified. It is true that `wait` fails immediately because it runs in a subshell and cannot access its parent's processes, but the program would not run as expected even if you used a command that did work.

The `if` statement runs a program and checks if its exit status is zero or non-zero. When you use backticks, the if statement will take the *output* of the process, try to run it as a program, and then use the exit code for that process. So the program isn't failing because `wait` fails, but rather it fails because `wait` does not produce any output.

You can make the script work by using `echo` inside the backticks:

```
if `echo wait $!`; then
    echo success
else
    echo failure
fi
```

Or just remove the backticks; easier for everyone.